# Are there NPCs that can charge my items in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm currently roleplaying non-caster character, who strictly avoids casting any spells. That means I cannot charge any soul gems by myself. Are there any NPCs that can charge my magic items for me?

Comment: Not sure about NPC's but there are two options. Enchant / buy a weapon with Soul trap or pick the Soul Siphon skill in the enchant tree - "Death blows to creatures (not people) capture 5% of the victim's soul, recharging the weapon"

Comment: Recharging a weapon using a charged soul gem (which you can find and buy, you don't have to fill one yourself) doesn't use up magicka, it just consumes the soul gem.  If you're not okay with that, why are you okay with using a magic weapon?

Comment: Doesn't the Thane weapons you get charge soul gems if you kill an enemy within a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using the following method for capturing souls, which does not require casting any spells. Thus, I can suggest this as another option.

1- Buy a weapon with "soul steal" enchantment. (The hunters in Winterrun sell one)

2- Disenchant to learn the "soul steal" enchantment.

3- Enchant a weapon of your choice with "soul steal" enchantment. (I use a bow for this.)

4- Whenever you kill a creature with this new weapon, you can capture its soul provided you have a gem available. You can then use the gem to recharge your weapons.

Comment: +1, although enchanting the weapon could count as casting a spell. It's a magic skill, at the least. You could of course just use the weapon you bought.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question proper: There are no NPCs who can charge your items for you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Although there were [rechargers in Oblivion](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Recharging), there are none in Skyrim.

In addition to using a weapon enchanted with soul trap (bought or made), you can also take advantage of a perk that automatically recharges your weapons.

**[Soul Siphon](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_(Skyrim)#Perks)**

> Death blows to creatures, but not people, trap 5% of the victim's soul, recharging the weapon

Of course, this requires that you level Enchanting up to 40, which you might not want to do if you're not a caster. You could always pay for training, rather than actually enchanting things.

Answer (score 0):

I learned by experience that companions that are given weapons enchanted with soul trap can fill soul gems, but you also have to give them empty soul gems suitable to the size of the victim.
Try to limit their weapon inventory so they are more apt to use the enchanted one.
A variety of soul gems is recommended because companions aren't selective about what they kill.